# Si tengo una matriz, ¿Cómo puedo verificar que, si uno quiere agregar un elemento en una fila negativa, me arroje una excepción?

Tags: java, junit

soy nuevo con JUnit y estoy practicando los asserts utilizando una matriz. Ahora, quiero crear un método llamado agregarElementoFilaNegativaTest que verifique que, si uno quiere agregar un elemento en una fila negativa, éste arroje una excepción.

Para poder Testear que no se pueda agregar un elemento en una fila negativa, y que arroje una excepción en caso de que lo hagan, se me ocurrió algo como hacer assertsTrue(i>0, numeroIngresado), pero no estoy seguro de que eso realmente funcione

Estoy usando la version JUnit 5.

Éstas son las funciones que tengo:

```
public class MatrizAdyacencia {

    private boolean[][] _ady;
    private int cantElementos=0;
    
    
    public MatrizAdyacencia(int cant)
    {
        cantElementos = cant;
        _ady = new boolean[cant][cant];
    }
    
    public void agregarElemento(int i, int j)
    {
        _ady[i][j] = true;
        _ady[j][i] = true;
    }
    
    public void eliminarElemento(int i, int j)
    {
        _ady[i][j] = false;
        _ady[j][i] = false;
    }
    
    public boolean existeElemento(int i, int j)
    {
        return _ady[i][j];
    }
    
    public int getCantidadElementos()
    {
        int cont=0;
        for(int i=0; i<=cantElementos-1; i++)
        {
           for(int j=0; j<=cantElementos-1; j++)
               if(_ady[i][j]==true)
                   cont++;
        }
        cont = cont/2;
        return cont;
    }
}
```

Comment: Debes poner también el código del Test con lo que has intentado. Tampoco dices cual versión de JUnit estás usando.

Comment: Y si pruebas lo que dices que quieres probar y miras qué pasa? Luego traes ese resultado y nos cuentas? Lo bueno de programar es que, a menos que programes cosas con explosivos o combustible, nada estalla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comprobar que el método lanza una excepción al agregar un elemento, podría ser tan simple cómo:

```
 Assertions.assertThrows( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class,() -> matriz.agregarElemento( -1, 1 ) );
```

Básicamente intentas agregar un elemento en índices negativos y le dices a  `JUnit` que en ese caso, espere una excepción.

La prueba completa se vería:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class MatrizAdyacenciaTest {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Agregar elemento usando una fila negativa debe lanzar una excepción")
    void agregarElementoFilaNegativaTest() {
        MatrizAdyacencia matriz = new MatrizAdyacencia( 4 );
        Assertions.assertThrows( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class,
                () -> matriz.agregarElemento( -1, 1 ) );
    }
}
```